# Best approach to backup database: save idb file vs mysqldump

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backups

I've a mysql server running on docker and with a /var/mysql folder mounted to a local hard drive.

this server has several databases in production and is subject to a daily backup routine, the backup script isn't the ideal one but it handles the task...
among other things it saves the whole /var/mysql folder [with all idb files] into a zip format and sends to another server for storage....

I'm not dbms expert so my question is, saving these files is better or worse than using a tool like mysqldump to save the database as script?

in my head as long as our mysql server is running on a docker and i can always restore the exact same version/passwords i can simple copy these idb files into a new server and the whole database structure will be preserved while if i use a mysqldump to extract the database creation/population sql i will need a two step backup restore...

so my question is, what is the correct approach? is there any problem of copying the whole folder structure like i am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Usually moving db files from **working** instance without stopping it or locking database files is a bad idea.
The term of copying raw db files is named "physical backup". This is the best idea for enterprise solutions with big amounts of data. It is also the fastest way to restore databases. [Mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) backup data as a script and restores databases by recreating them, it involves indexing and so on...
The main problem of your solution is that files of database you copy can be **changed** during copying operation. This can corrupt your data and make your backup useless.
The correct way to make a physical backup involves [**locking mysql instance**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-instance-for-backup.html) or stopping myslq service before copying raw files. During lock files on disk are not changed and you can perform safe copy.
To sum up: the approach of performing a backup you actually do is bad and can cost you all stored data. I recommend you to consider preparing script for locking instance, copying raw files and unlocking instance. If your db is not so big, you can use mysqldump to perform logical backup in the easiest way having your mysql service online.
In both cases you can perform it as a script run by cron inside your container - this is how I would do this job.
[More about recovery types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-types.html)

Comment: you text is very unclear, first you saying that moving files is a bad idea... right next sentence you say is the best idea for enterprise

Comment: This is not what I said. Read my response again carefully or read documents I have attached. There is difference between proper physical backup on offline/locked database files and "just copy" db files as you do. This is a rule: do not move/copy files from your working database server, because it can be changed during this operation.